# Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment VBA Custom UI Call

Tags: excel, vba

I added the following XML code to an add-in file.  The tab and buttons show up on the ribbon just fine, but when I click the Budget button, it gives me the error message "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".  I've read that I need to add "control as iribboncontrol" in the arguments of the sub I'm calling, which I've done and I still get the same error.  However, when I open th VBE and manually run the sub, it works just fine.  Does anyone know what the problem is?

Here is the XML.  Again, I'm just trying to click the first button, "Budget".

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="CFA Reporting">
                <group id="customGroup" label="Query">
                    <button id="customButton1" label="Budget" imageMso="FrameCreateAbove" size="large" onAction="GetBudgetTable" />
                    <button id="customButton2" label="Actuals" imageMso="FrameCreateBelow" size="large" onAction="GetActualsTable" />
                    <button id="customButton3" label="Budget + Actuals" imageMso="FrameCreateRight" size="large" onAction="GetBudgetandActualsTable" />
                    <button id="customButton4" label="Actual Drilldown" imageMso="ZoomPrintPreviewExcel" size="large" onAction="ActualDrilldown" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Here is the sub I'm calling.

```
Sub GetBudgetTable(control As IRibbonControl)

Dim dbFilePath As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim cell As Range
Dim Year As String
Dim SQL As String

'For Each cell In Range("A1:A100")
    'If InStr(1, cell.Name, "SQL", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        Year = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Range("Year").Value
        SQL = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Range("BudgetSQL").Value

        'pulls budget
        dbFilePath = "H:\CORP\CFR-2011_to_Current\Budget\2015\Budget Variance\Budget Variance - Pivot\Test\More Tests\Administrative\Database\" & Year & " Budget.accdb"
        Set db = Access.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(dbFilePath, False, True)
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Budget Table").Range("A2:AJ80000").ClearContents
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Budget Table").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        db.Close

        'updates pivot table data source and refreshes pivot table
        DataSource = "Budget Table!R1C1:R" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Budget Table").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count & "C" & _
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Budget Table").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report").PivotTables("Pivot").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, _
            DataSource)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report").PivotTables("Pivot").RefreshTable

End Sub
```

I also read at the link below that I need to have a reference to the Microsoft Office 12.0 Objects Library.  I have Excel 2010 and I have Microsoft Office 14.0 Objects Library referenced, so I wouldn't think this would be the problem, would it?

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/wrong-number-of-arguments-or-invalid-property/6cb6cf17-f1ab-49b2-8a82-2d67521e3bf5?auth=1

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Your XML seems fine. I believe the error is within your `GetBudgetTable` sub, step thru it in VBE and see where it occurs.

Comment: Agree with Patrick: which line is causing the error? This sounds like a problem with a method call. Take a look at ChangePivotCache near the end: you have a close parentheses following DataSource but no open parentheses. Try removing that closing parenthesis.

Comment: @CindyMeister I'll look through the sub and see which is causing the error.  The opening parentheses is on the line above it before xlDatabase.

Comment: Put in  a break point at the beginning of the Sub (click in the line and press F9) then the focus will jump to your code when the Ribbon control calls it. Then F8 to step through. You should then see which line "hiccups".

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  So, the workbook I had open is a workbook I use to test the macros before later adding them to the add-in.  One of those test macros is an old version of the GetBudgetTable macro, which is the name of the macro that's called when I click the add-in button "Budget".  The test macro doesn't have the "Control as IRibbonControl" argument, so I think what happens when I click the add-in button is Excel first looks in the workbook's VBA modules for the macro and if it doesn't find it there then it goes to the add-in.

That makes sense, because in the XML code, I'm only referencing "GetBudgetTable".  It doesn't say anything about the file path for that macro or any other information that would differentiate it from the test macro that goes by the same name.

I discovered this because I opened a blank workbook, created the necessary objects in order for the macro to run, clicked the Budget button, and it worked fine - because there was no other GetBudgetTable macro in the blank workbook.

I hope I didn't waste everyone's time too much, but I appreciate everyone's suggestions!